# Rails: belongs_to multiple > Methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, table-relationships

I just finished the Michael Hartl Rails Tutorial. Trying to make something of my own.

I am having trouble with getting rails to understand the relationships I'm trying to create. I'll try to simplify this as much as possible. A tree with branches, twigs and leaves would be apt, but...

I'll use the parent child format as an example. So naturally I have users, and let's say users create families.

So:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :families
 has_many :parents
 has_many :children

end

Class Family < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :user
 has_many :parents

end

Class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to: :user
 belongs_to: :family
 has_many: :children

end

Class Child < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :parent

end
```

As you can see, I want a child to belong to the parent which belongs to the family, but the child itself does not belong to a family except through the parent. Sad if this weren't a metaphor, but true in this particular case. ;)

I have tried under Parent:

```
has_many :children, through: :parent
```

and

```
has_many :children, through: :family
```

But that didn't work.

When I try to use:

```
User.family.new
```

or

```
User.child.new
```

...it says the method doesn't exist. I take that to mean that it isn't understanding the relationships.

What am I doing wrong?

If it's relevant, the only thing in the family, parent, child tables for now are these columns:

```
  t.string :content
  t.integer :user_id
```

Comment: You're calling `User.family.new`, `User.family` is undefined. An AR relation doesn't create class methods, only instance methods so if you have `@parent` you can call `@parent.children` provided you have `has_many :children` in the parent method. In this case just call `Child.new` or `@parent.children.build`, you need a parent to do this

Comment: Forgive me, just coming off the railstutorial to try my hand at my own app, but in the tutorial you have Microposts and Users, and when you set up Micropost belongs_to User and User has_many Microposts you can then do User.microposts or User.micropost.new.  Why is this different?

Comment: The use of `User` is to call the model named 'User'. It is not an actual user, it is the model you're calling. `User.create` will create an instancied object User. For instance: `user_object = User.create`: the `user_object` is an instancied object of type User.

Comment: Just an observation, but wouldn't it make the most sense to have Child and Parent be a subclass of User, and have a class Family, which has_many parents (and has_many children through parents), and parents which has_many children. Maybe I'm just overanalyzing your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have these methods:

```
User.family.new
User.child.new
```

When you define `has_many` association, you just have these methods to create new object associated:

```
collection.build(attributes = {}, …)
collection.create(attributes = {})
```

Follow Rails guide:

> collection is replaced with the symbol passed as the first argument to
>   has_many

You can look at this [has_many association reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference) for more info.
So, If `User` want create new family or child, you need to use these methods:

```
user = User.create(name: "ABC") # create new user and save to database. 
user.families.build  # create new family belongs to user
user.children.build  # create new children belongs to user

user.families.create # create new family belongs to user and save it to database.
user.children.create # create new child belongs to user and save it to database.
```

If you want to get children belongs to parent which belongs to family, you can modify your association:

```
Class Family < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :user
 has_many :parents
 has_many :children, through: :parents # Get children through parents
end

Class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to: :user
 belongs_to: :family
 has_many: :children

end

Class Child < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :parent

end
```

Now, you can get all children belongs to parents which belongs to a family ( I suppost family have id = 1) with:

```
 f = Family.find(1) # Find a family with id = 1
 f.children # Get all children in family.
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I was trying to do it the way the railstutorial suggested. Rather than doing Micropost.create he suggested creating the relationship and going user.micropost.create instead.  This is what I was trying to achieve.  I think your post might have solved my problem, not sure yet. It's definitely more complex than microposts and your average message board.