# Rails - How to start my database and relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I trying to make a simple app to register families. [I looked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614063/rails-belongs-to-multiple-methods) first, but i don't find my answer. Here is my question :

I have 3 tables : Parents Children and Families that I'm trying to connect. 
A parent got some string ( name, address ... ), a child got ( name, age, allergy ... ).
A family is build of 2 parents and 0 or more children, with some extra columns ( emergency number ... )

My problem is: how should i write family table to be able to connect 2 different parents with their parent_id and multiple children ? Should i create 2 columns for parents and set foreign keys. And for the children should I create a lot of columns ? Is there an auto ajustement solution ?

I'm thinking of making some extras tables like children_list and parents_list and connect them to family.

If you got some documentation about this situation, i'll appreciate reading it.

Thanks.

edit :

I try few things and i think data bases are not the problem. Family table is the joint table with multiple columns and i use the many through association to link parents and children.
I need to find a way to add new rows when i select many parents/children in the family view form, otherwise app stop because i try to set two times the parent_id column with two different values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally:

I find my answer in the [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=comments). Here is what i've done :

- Family table
- Parents table with the family_id column
- Children table with the family_id column

In the Models :

- Family has_many parents and children, got attr_accessible :parents_attributes ( and children ), got accepts_nested_attributes_for :parents, :children
- Children and Parents belongs_to family

Now i can set my family views to ask for parents and children attributes and it will fill in the right table !

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using the ancestry gem. Rails does not support mutli-table inheritance out of the box.  You would have to implement your own.  It is best to use single table inheritance.  A link to the aforementioned gem is below.  I have used this gem extensively.

https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry

Here is a link explaining in detail your above issue

[Multi Table Inheritance with rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022802/multi-table-inheritance-with-rails-3)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm reading your doc at the moment. I'm not sure ancestry is what I'm looking for. I check railscasts and this one is interesting: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1. 
The many_through may be correct but i need to adjust either the controller or the view. The family table has got only one parent_id cell so i need to make a new row when another one is set but those two rows have to share an id to identify that a family may have two parents.

Comment: I'm reading again your second link. It's definitely useful to understand my situation. I'll try to solve this today! Thanks again.